# How can I get full information of product in cart

Tags: magento2

How can I get full information of product in cart 
I want to get all info of my product which is in cart coz In my cart it will only get name sky and id, but I want custom attributes also ...

```
 [
    {
        "item_id": 43,
        "sku": "SoundBot SB571",
        "qty": 1,
        "name": "SoundBot SB571 12W Bluetooth Speakers",
        "price": 1399,
        "product_type": "simple",
        "quote_id": "3"
    }
   ]
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? if you have a configurable product, it will show its for example color or size. There is an option to add SKU also. What else do you need there?

Comment: I need color and single image for that check my post again I add some of response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where you are want your data. But when you refer cart it refers to Quote and Items

You can get All your data from the **Item** Object Itself

For Example If you want Product Id or any of its information you can call this way.

```
$item->getProduct()->getId();
$item->getProduct()->getSku();
$item->getProduct()->getName();
$item->getProduct()->getPrice();
```

You can get Item object from quote and Quote Object from checkout session if required.